# How do you efficiently repeat a 2D numpy array with an offset?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I have a 2D numpy array of points with three columns, and I want to repeat these points in the x direction, producing a new array which has the original set of points, plus a number of 'repeated' points which are translated (1, 2, 3, ..., n) times in the x direction by some vector <c, 0, 0>.

To be clear, say I had the point [0.1, 2.0, 5.0] in the original array, and I wanted to 'repeat' it 5 times using a vector <2, 0, 0>, I would have the following in the final array:

```
new_array = [[0.1, 2.0, 5.0], [2.1, 2.0, 5.0], [4.1, 2.0, 5.0], [6.1, 2.0, 5.0], [8.1, 2.0, 5.0], [10.1, 2.0, 5.0]]
```

Is there a way of doing this efficiently using inbuilt numpy vectorisation?

Comment: That's a 2D array with three columns

Comment: What happens when you have two points in the array: `[[x0, y0, z0], [x1, y1, z1]]`? Do you want the repetitions interleaved, or not?

Comment: Thanks very much for the corrections! I don't care what order the points are in so long as they are repeated. In my own implementation I have similar points grouped together, as a consequence of the np.repeat() function output.

Interesting term though, is interleaved the common industry term used for this sort of action? I was struggling earlier to think of such a term when querying search engines before asking the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

point = [0.1, 2, 5]
vector = [2, 0, 0]
n = 5

a = np.zeros((n, len(vector)))
a[1:] = vector
a = np.cumsum(a, axis=0) + point
```

`a[1:] = vector` will create the array

```
[[0. 0. 0.]
 [2. 0. 0.]
 [2. 0. 0.]
 [2. 0. 0.]
 [2. 0. 0.]]
```

which is the difference you want per row. You then cumulatively summate them and add the point as offset.

Comment: Thanks very much, this gave me an idea for how to do it, I'm actually dealing with structured arrays, so the problem is slightly different but a similar method can be applied! I'll post my own method once I'm done.

Answer (score 1):

A variation on the accepted answer:

```
In [33]: point = np.array([0.1, 2.0, 5.0])
In [34]: vector = np.array([2,0,0])
In [35]: np.arange(5)[:,None]*vector
Out[35]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 0],
       [4, 0, 0],
       [6, 0, 0],
       [8, 0, 0]])
In [36]: np.arange(5)[:,None]*vector + point
Out[36]: 
array([[0.1, 2. , 5. ],
       [2.1, 2. , 5. ],
       [4.1, 2. , 5. ],
       [6.1, 2. , 5. ],
       [8.1, 2. , 5. ]])
```

Your comment mentions a structured array.  For example if `point` has 3 fields, and you want to modify the first:

```
In [37]: arr = np.array([(0.1, 2.0, 5.0)], dtype='f,f,f')
In [38]: arr
Out[38]: array([(0.1, 2., 5.)], dtype=[('f0', '<f4'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<f4')])
In [41]: arr = arr.repeat(5)
In [42]: arr
Out[42]: 
array([(0.1, 2., 5.), (0.1, 2., 5.), (0.1, 2., 5.), (0.1, 2., 5.),
       (0.1, 2., 5.)], dtype=[('f0', '<f4'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<f4')])
In [43]: arr['f0']
Out[43]: array([0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1], dtype=float32)
In [44]: arr['f0'] += np.arange(5)*2
In [45]: arr
Out[45]: 
array([(0.1, 2., 5.), (2.1, 2., 5.), (4.1, 2., 5.), (6.1, 2., 5.),
       (8.1, 2., 5.)], dtype=[('f0', '<f4'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<f4')])
```

You can't modify all 3 fields at the same time.  Math does not work across fields.

Comment: Yeah, that is unfortunate isn't it! I managed to find a way around it however, will post the answer now. Thanks very much for responding though! Your method is very elegant, the only problem is the vector I use has to be general (it represents an axis direction in a crystal structure).

Answer (score 0):

My own answer, thanks to some prompting from the two answers already given. I have the answer for a structured array also - if anyone is interested I can edit this post and add it below.

Given a starting array: `array = np.array([[1, 2, 3], ..., [10, 9, 8]])`, a vector: `vector = np.array([1, 3, 5])` and a desired number of repetitions: `repeat = 5`. You can use the following code:

```
new_array = np.repeat(array, repeat)
vector_shifts = np.array([vector*index for index in range(0, repeat)])
vector_shifts = vector_shifts[np.newaxis, :]
vector_shifts = np.repeat(vector_shifts, array.shape[0], axis=0)
```

`np.newaxis` creates an extra axis which stops shifts grouping when repeated along, which is the standard `np.repeat()` behaviour. For example `np.repeat(np.array([[1, 2, 4], [2, 3, 5]], 2)` gives an output: `np.array([[1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 4], [2, 3, 5], [2, 3, 5]]`.

```
vector_shifts = vector_shifts.reshape(vector_shifts.shape[0]*vector_shifts.shape[1], 3)
```

This removes the additional axis added for `np.repeat()` to perform as desired. Finally, the vector shifts can be added to the new array to give an expanded array of repeated points.

```
new_array += vector_shift
```